# Simple RestKit login without using JSON

Tags: ios, authentication, restkit

It's been two days that I'm looking for a simple code for RestKit API for logging into a website without using JSON. Here is the code that I wrote so far:

```
- (void)login
{
    [RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://Mywebsite.com/login.php"];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"user" forKey:@"username"];
    [params setObject:@"pass" forKey:@"password"];
    [params setObject:@"login" forKey:@"type"];
    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/login" params:params delegate:self];

}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response
{
    NSLog(@"HTTP status code:     %d", response.statusCode);
    NSLog(@"HTTP status message:  %@", [response localizedStatusCodeString]);
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSRange range = [[error localizedDescription] rangeOfString:@"-1012"];
    if (range.length > 0){
        //Do whatever here to handle authentication failures
    }
    RKLogError(@"Hit error: %@", error);
}
```

Here is the log that I receive:

```
2012-09-08 21:44:14.633 RestKitTest[889:fb03] I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit initialized...
2012-09-08 21:44:15.010 RestKitTest[889:fb03] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:369 Network availability has been determined for reachability observer <RKReachabilityObserver: 0x6c5a560 host=0.0.0.0 isReachabilityDetermined=YES isMonitoringLocalWiFi=NO reachabilityFlags=-R -----l->
2012-09-08 21:44:21.021 RestKitTest[889:fb03] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:676 Status Code: 404
2012-09-08 21:44:21.036 RestKitTest[889:fb03] HTTP status code:     404
2012-09-08 21:44:21.090 RestKitTest[889:fb03] HTTP status message:  not found
```

Any idea how I can fix this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: @hlfcoding Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why don't you want to use JSON?

Comment: I'd say it `404`s because you set `baseURL` as    `http://Mywebsite.com/login.php` yet you POST as `post:@"/login"`. Do you really want to access `http://Mywebsite.com/login.php/login`?

Comment: @mja Thank you so much, this is exactly the problem, if you post your answer I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Because the website that I want to use its web service, doesn't give me the JSON as a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it `404`s because you set `baseURL` as `http://Mywebsite.com/login.php` yet you POST as `post:@"/login"`. Do you really want to access `http://Mywebsite.com/login.php/login`?

The baseURL should be set to a common prefix to all your backend calls, in your case `http://Mywebsite.com`, the resource itself should be posted as `post:@"/login.php"`. The resource name and baseURL are concatenated before the request is sent.

Comment: Thank you @mja, my last question, if I want to make this username and password persistence to use the other web services what should I do? because right now it will log in but when I want to post something as a user it gives me this error that you are not log in. I fixed this issue in `ASIHTTPRequest` API by writing this line of code:  `[loginRequest setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];`    but I don't know if RestKit has equivalent code to make user and pass persistence.

Comment: Did you tried to set the username and password to your `RKClient` instance `[[RKClient sharedClient] setUsername:@"user"]` ;

Comment: I set the username and password as you said after this line of code in my login method `[[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/login" params:params delegate:self]; ` but it is still gives me this error that I'm not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide info on what `login.php` is doing. I don't see why it should 404 if the script url resolves correctly.

Also, if that PHP script does a redirect on success, you should use the `RKClient` method  `post:usingBlock:` and inside that block do `request.followRedirect = NO;`. That way you'll get the correct status code, if you are returning one.

If may also help to log more of the response:

```
NSLog(@"Header fields: %@", response.allHeaderFields);
NSLog(@"Body: %@", response.bodyAsString);
```

Comment: If the user inputs the correct username and password login.php will direct him/her to the home page, but if the user inputs the wrong user of pass it stays on login page, so I have to parse the xml code after inputting user and pass to see if it is on the home page or it is still on login page.

Comment: I added two NSLog that you suggest, and here is the response that I received: `2012-09-09 17:27:36.166 RestKitTest[492:fb03] Header fields: {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sun, 09 Sep 2012 22:27:35 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = Apache;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
}
2012-09-09 17:27:36.167 RestKitTest[492:fb03] Body: No input file specified.`

Comment: Based on that log of the response body, it looks like your php script is dying on an error. Maybe you're not passing something it needs. Also keep in mind you should be making the request to the actual script/endpoint/form-action that logs the user in, and not the script that just shows the login page.